# Does slim syntax highlighter exists for Adobe Brackets?

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, slim-lang, adobe-brackets

Does anyone know of a way i can get slim syntax to be highlighted in Adobe Brackets? I really like Adobe Brackets but my slim files are ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Brackets uses [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) editor, so there needs to be a "mode" implemented in CodeMirror that Brackets can use for slim files.

Randy

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can Highlight the Syntax** of your Slim files in Adobe Brackets.

Try [brackets-slim extension](https://github.com/lchamb/brackets-slim).

This will do what you request.